# React controlled contenteditable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable, draftjs

hi I'm trying to create a react contenteditable div component that works like an input field but with some additional features that I want to implement, but since there are just few features, I want to implement it myself and not use something like slatejs or draftjs that do so much heavy lifting.

my idea is that I should have a controlled contenteditable div that I listen on events that insert some text. (like general idea of [react controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components))

it looked straightforward. I should listen on keydown events and on each event I just insert the corresponding character(event.key) into my state. however I found that on mobile devices with touch keyboards this value(event.key) is always 'Unidentified'.

also sometimes the input events have a 'data' property that determines the inserted value. but in touch keyboard that event doesn't have 'data' property.

so my question is how can we get inserted characters in a way that works globally on desktop and mobile? how do draftjs and slatejs authors detect inserted characters (even on touch mobile) and update their state?

Comment: that's why `draft.js` not support mobile as well.

Comment: I don't know about draft.js support but slate.js supports mobile as I tested it. and they use onBeforeInput for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally got the answer
it turns out that in react there is an event called `onBeforeInput` that can be used on contenteditable divs and has a property called `data` that corresponds to the text that is going to be inserted (on both mobile and desktop). this event is cancelable so you can call `preventDefault` on it and update your state.
unfortunately this event was not mentioned in any of react docs (!!) and I found it from an issue on their github repo.

Comment: I believe `beforeinput` is a vanilla JavaScript event, but it isn't very well-documented, either. On MDN, the event's page, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeinput, is linked to from, e.g., the InputEvent page, but is red, meaning it doesn't exist yet. On another note, React's version seems more full-featured, for example it has the `data` property even on browsers that don't support it natively yet, like Firefox.

Comment: Not sure if wrong or this information is outdated but if I `console.log` beforeinput event, it says `canceable: false`.

Comment: Looks like almost 60% of users don't have support for `beforeinput` in their browser https://caniuse.com/?search=beforeinput

Comment: @ArneHugo No, actually it's not like that. It seems that React under the hood converts the `beforeinput` event into something specific to each browser that has good support. for chrome it is `textInput` (notice the uppercase i).

Comment: Nice. By using `onBeforeInput`, is it possible to change the value of the `contentEditable` without breaking undo (`ctrl+Z`)?

Comment: @ArneHugo I think if you want to use it as a controlled component, you need to take control of everything and handle the `undo` yourself. But it's surely worth a try!

Comment: How do you know where the **caret** was at when a key was pressed (known through `data` property of the event), so a character could be added to the state?

Comment: if you are using ```contentEditable``` for only controlling text.
you can use:

```onInput={ (e: any) => console.log(e.target.textContent) }```
which will give you full text inside component.